# Set All Contacts as Receiving Mail in Thunderbird 3.0

Tags: html, contacts, thunderbird

In TB 3.0, I know you can set properties for a contact to indicate that e-mail should be sent as html.  Rather than opening
every window/contact is there some way I can set this as a default and also edit a file where I can set this property
for all current contacts?

Thanks,

--MLD

Answer (score 0):

From the AddressBook, I multiselect and go to

- Right click
- Edit properties collectively
- and then the option is in there

Not sure if this is native behavior or if it is because I installed http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/morecols-en.html

Comment: Not question related but that website has bad reputation, just a warning.